# Php: which is the fastest string-hashing method for filesystem?

Tags: php

I want to cache stuffes to disk, and of course what I put to the disk must be "safe". I was doing some measurements:

```
foreach (['md5', 'crc32', 'base64_encode'] as $item)
{
    $m = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 1; $i < 1000000; $i++)
    {
        $a = 'adat'.str_repeat('x', mt_rand(10, 1000));
        $a = $item($a);
    }
    echo $item.'<br>';
    echo microtime(true)-$m;
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

the results:

```
md5
1.9821128845215
crc32
1.8771071434021
base64_encode
1.110063791275
```

so base64_encode won, but it generates a long string, so its easy to exceed the 256 character limit. Is there any faster encoding method which Im not aware of? It dont have to be bi-directioned

Comment: a) you're comparing apples and oranges. md5 and crc32 don't *encode* anything, they create a **hash**. base64, on the other hand, *encodes* and can be *decoded*, and has a length dependent on the input length. which is unsuitable for indexing. (plus you could just use the input itself with the same result and better performance) b) define "being safe"? c) don't you think using an existing caching engine would be far more efficient than rolling your own? d) "is there any faster method" - is **asking to recommend a resource** and therefore OT

Comment: CRC32 and MD5 are hash algorithms, where you can never get the back to the original data, but check its integrity. Base64 is an encoding scheme to represent binary data with printable characters, which can be reverted. They do completely different things. What do you want to do?

Comment: @king_nak, ok, it doesnt matter if encoding or hashing. I just want to convert strings to such form that they can be stored on disk safely

Comment: By "safe" are you asking for the ability to secure the data? Base64 won't secure the data. MD5 also can't be decrypted without brute force and instead produces a hash (although MD5 is now seen as a cracked algorithm and shouldn't be used). So do you want to be able to access the raw data in the future or do you want a hash or the data? If you want to be able to access the raw data I would recommend using SHA256.

Comment: no! By secure: it doesnt contain utf, slash, etc chacacters, only numbers and characters a-z

Comment: @JohnSmith So you don't want to be able to access the raw data in the future? Also ciphers output is encoded into hex code and therefore will only be A-F 0-9

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$hashValue = hash('tiger160,3', $string);
```

**tiger** has good length and good speed.

Also [in php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) you can find useful comments that describes features of different hash algorithms.

Comment: But it may be not enough length. crc32 - 8 chars and tiger160,3 - 40 chars. It depends on requirements and specific task.